# Css table th left border across line

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to apply left border on my th element in table. The problem is, when I put border CSS style there is an empty "space" after line (tr) - see image.

```
<table>
<tr>
   <th>
       ....
   <th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>
       ....
   <th>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am using  `border-left: 1px solid #2185d0;` for all th elements

[image]

But I want full line like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: What about setting tr top and bottom border to none ?

Comment: please add the all codes. so all html and css codes.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-collapse/

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps add this to your css?

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the CSS styles you are attributing to the table. It would really help if you could provide code snippits for that (specifically). 
What I suspect is that you have either margin or padding settings that are preventing the table cells from touching eachother, thus producing a space between the border lines.